# Creating custom post in wordpress error

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress is throwing this error message:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for `_x()`, called in "directory/posttypes.php" on line 8 and defined in "directory/l10n.php on line 250

postypes.php:

```
        // Add new post type for Recipes
add_action('init', 'cooking_recipes_init');
function cooking_recipes_init() 
{
    $args = array(
        'label' => _x('Recipes'),
        'singular_label' => _x('Recipe'),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments')
    ); 
    register_post_type('recipes',$args);
}
```

functions.php:

```
include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/posttypes.php');
```

l10n.php:

```
function _x( $text, $context, $domain = 'default' ) {
    return translate_with_gettext_context( $text, $context, $domain );
}
```

any advice would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Why do you use _x if you don't provide context to gettext? Use `__()` or `_e()` instead.

Comment: @PaulSelitskas, you wouldn't want to use `_e()` in this instance, since we only want to `return` the translated string...not `echo` it.

Comment: @rnevius yes you wouldn't! I was just pointing out that `__()`/`_e()` and `_x()`/`_ex()` are not exactly the same.

Comment: You should replace this with __(), but only to those where the error occurs at. As per this guide: https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/missing-argument-2-for-_x-error-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

As the error states, the [`_x()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x) function has two required parameters: (1) the string of text to be translated, (2) context information for the translators.

If you don't need to include context, you can use [`__()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2). If you don't need to translate the string...don't use either function.

Either of the following would be valid:

```
'label' => __('Recipes'),
'singular_label' => __('Recipe'),
```

or...

```
'label' => 'Recipes',
'singular_label' => 'Recipe',
```